# How to recursively print parents of leaves?

Tags: c++, recursion, avl-tree

I need to print out all the parent nodes with a leaf (a leaf has no children and has a height of 0) as one of their children. I got it to traverse the first side and return the first parent with one leaf but after that return, I'm not sure what to do, as I try to go down the right side and I now get a segfault and I imagine if it traverses two sides of a node then it will eventually return to that node and get stuck.

What I have:

```
void BST::printLeafParent(Tnode* cur){
    if(getHeight(cur->right)== 0) {
            cout << cur->key;
            if(getHeight(cur->left) ==0)
                    return;
            else{
                    printLeafParent(cur->left);
            }
    }
    printLeafParent(cur->right);
    if(getHeight(cur->left) == 0){
            cout << cur->key;
            return;
    }
    else{
            printLeafParent(cur->left);
    }
}

void BST::printLeafParent(){
    if(getHeight(root->right)== 0) {
            cout << root->key;
            if(getHeight(root->left) ==0)
                    return;
            else
                    printLeafParent(root->left);
    }
    printLeafParent(root->right);
    if(getHeight(root->left) == 0){
            cout << root->key;
            return;
    }
    else{
            printLeafParent(root->left);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm just missing something simple but I'm having a hard time understanding it/finding it.

Comment: I don't see any tests for NULL pointers.  You should use your debugger and examine the call stack after the segfault occurs.  This will inform you whether you have a NULL pointer access, or something else (a stack overflow, for example).

Comment: *"I now get a segfault "* -- on which line? What are the values of your variables at that point? (A debugger makes this part of debugging easier.) Perhaps it would be easier to debug if you used simpler input, perhaps the subtree of your current example that has `he` as its root?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example output, the tree traversal is:

1. process right subtree
2. check "current node" for leaf of parent
3. process left subtree

Here is a re-written one might look like.

```
bool BST::isLeaf(Tnode* node)
{
  if (node != nullptr && node->left == nullptr && node->right == nullptr) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void BST::printLeafParent(Tnode* node)
{
  if (node == nullptr) {
    return;
  }

  printLeafParent(node->right);

  if (isLeaf(node->left) || isLeaf(node->right)) {
    std::cout << node->key << ' ';
  }

  printLeafParent(node->left);

}

void BST::printLeafParent()
{
  printLeafParent(root);
}
```

Comment: "keep the recursion simple" is a bit vague. Could you explain what you did to improve the code? Answers that rely on code to explain everything tend to be not useful in the long run.

Comment: It is true that you edited your answer. However, you did not add any explanation of your changes, so my critique still stands.